# NetConnection.Connect.Failed , chat program

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chat, voice

i got a project on school and we are supposed to make a voice chat program.
do you guys got any preferd turtorials? the error with our current program is NetConnection.Connect.Failed, this is because the RTMP server cant connect. we tryd to solve this problem but we aren't allowed to host the server on our school network. maby you guys got some tips about this?

thanks for reading,

J.

Comment: Please show us code you have tried

Comment: @GopalJoshi
$rtmp_server="rtmp://localhost:1935/videowhisper"; 

$rtmp_amf="AMF3";

$rtmfp_server="rtmfp://stratus.adobe.com/f1533cc06e4de4b56399b10d-1a624022ff71/";